# Java TCP client printing extra characters on receive

Tags: java, c, tcp, bufferedreader

```
String buffer = argv[1] + " " + argv[2] + " " + argv[3];
Socket sock = new Socket(ip, port);
DataOutputStream send = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader recv = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
send.writeBytes(buffer + '\n');

String result = recv.readLine();
System.out.println("From Server: " + result);
sock.close();
```

I have a java **TCP** client connecting to a server written in **C**. The client tells the server to multiply/add two numbers and the server sends the result. For some reason when I call `readLine()` it returns the string sent from the server along with part of the buffer.

For example, I send the server "multiply 10 10", the server sends back "100" and the client prints `100tiply1010`. I've already checked that the server is not at fault, and it works fine with a client written in **C**.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The client calls `readLine`. That means either the server is supposed to be sending lines or the client is broken. Is the server supposed to be sending lines? If so, did you 100% confirm that it does in fact send lines? If not, how is the client supposed to find the end of the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the server. It is sending back part of the request string in the response string. Possibly it is is null-terminating the response and you're expected to look for the null and ignore everything past it, and presumably the C client does that, but the server shouldn't be sending anything extra in the first place.

In other words the server is probably using `sizeof buffer` as the length argument to `send(),` rather than `strlen(buffer)` or possibly `strlen(buffer)+1` if the trailing null is part of the protocol. It all seems to be very poorly defined.

In any case using `readLine()` on data that isn't line-terminated isn't correct.

Comment: I wouldn't feel like an idiot, it isn't obvious. If the C client just does `printf()` of the received buffer for example it's easy to see why it looks like it works.